Tesseract for Python - strange OCR results - convert line of digits but fail to convert each individual one
Using Tesseract in python and getting inconsistent OCR result - it convert line of digits correctly but each separate digit it cannot convert.
For example for this image 1 Tesseract gives correct results (p0 is the image1)(https://i.sstatic.net/hAn9q.png):
pytesseract.image_to_string(p0, config=options)  #p0 is image https://i.sstatic.net/hAn9q.png
'431659\n'
but for each of the subcell which just have a digit (image 2)(https://i.sstatic.net/MxBaK.png) it gives empty result:
pytesseract.image_to_string(p1, config=options) #p1 is image 2 with first digit 4
''
I'm not sure how to get correct result. It is a very clear and simple image of a digit and Tesseract cannot OCR it even though it does it easily when it is an image of the row of digits.
I tried rescaling the individual cell but Tesseract just does not like single digits.

tesseact has optioons to work with words or single chars. It may have also problem when text is too small or when text has too small margin. It may preferre black text on white background - so it may need to convert to grey or even black-and-white

Tesseract doc: Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc

if you run tesseract --help-extra in console then you can see: Page segmentation modes:  10  Treat the image as a single character. - so you may try with --psm 10

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I tested your images with different Page segmentation modes
and both works for me for 8, 9, 10, 13.
I don't have to even resize it.
So you may have to use one of this values in option --psm

Full working code used for test:
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import pytesseract

for number in range(1, 3):
    image_path = f'0{number}.png'

    print(f'--- {image_path} ---') 
    
    img = Image.open(image_path)

    #w, h = img.size
    #print('old size:', w, h)
    #new_w = w * 2
    #new_h = h * 2
    #print('new size:', new_w, new_h)
    #img = img.resize((new_w, new_h), Image.Resampling.NEAREST)

    # Use Tesseract OCR to extract text
    for psm in range(0, 14):
        try:
            custom_config = fr'--oem 3 --psm {psm} -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.,-'
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,  lang='eng', config=custom_config)
            text = text.strip()  # remove `new line` at the end of text
            # Print the extracted text
            print(f"{psm:3} | Text:", text)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(f"{psm:3} | Exception:", ex)

Result:
--- 01.png ---

  0 | Exception: (1, 'Warning, detects only orientation with -l eng Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Too few characters. Skipping this page Error during processing.')
  1 | Text: 
  2 | Exception: (1, 'Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.')
  3 | Text: 
  4 | Text: 
  5 | Text: 
  6 | Text: 
  7 | Text: 
  8 | Text: 431659
  9 | Text: 431659
 10 | Text: 431659
 11 | Text: 
 12 | Text: 
 13 | Text: 431659

--- 02.png ---

  0 | Exception: (1, 'Warning, detects only orientation with -l eng Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Estimating resolution as 888 Too few characters. Skipping this page Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Too few characters. Skipping this page Error during processing.')
  1 | Text: 
  2 | Exception: (1, 'Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead. Estimating resolution as 888 Empty page!!')
  3 | Text: 
  4 | Text: 
  5 | Text: 
  6 | Text: 4
  7 | Text: 4
  8 | Text: 4
  9 | Text: 4
 10 | Text: 4
 11 | Text: 
 12 | Text: 
 13 | Text: 4


BTW:
If you run in console tesseract --help-extra then you see:
Page segmentation modes:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. (not implemented)
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
       bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.

